# c++ return from c'tor + default return values for err handling

Tags: c++, gcc, language-lawyer, return-type, clang++

I have a couple of macros, one returning a value and the other returning for void function case, basically calling the other one with its arguments and `(void)0`. When compiling it both with VS and GCC, I had some unexpected compilation issues for the cases where it's called from within a constructor.

I tried running the following, un-commenting each of the 5 cases with `gcc b.cpp` (gcc version 4.8.4), `clang c.bpp`(clang version 3.4-1) on ubuntu 14.04 and some VS2013 on win7,

```
#include <cstdio>

struct A {
    A() {
        return ((void)0);   // case 0 => gcc err,   clang ok,   msvc err
        //return (void)0;   // case 1 => gcc err,   clang ok,   msvc ok
        //return ();        // case 2 => gcc err,   clang err,  msvc err
        //return;           // case 3 => gcc ok,    clang ok,   msvc ok
        //;                 // case 4 => gcc ok,    clang ok,   msvc ok
    }
} a;

int main()
{
    printf("%p\n", &a);
}
```

I expected all to have a similar effect (Well I'm not sure about case 2) but instead I got some odd failiures...

case 2:

```
$ gcc b.cpp
b.cpp: In constructor ‘A::A()’:
b.cpp:7:17: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
         return ();
                 ^
b.cpp:7:17: error: returning a value from a constructor
$ clang b.cpp
b.cpp:7:17: error: expected expression
        return ();
                ^
1 error generated.
```

case 1:

```
$ gcc b.cpp
b.cpp: In constructor ‘A::A()’:
b.cpp:6:22: error: returning a value from a constructor
         return (void)0;
```

case 0:

```
$ gcc b.cpp
b.cpp: In constructor ‘A::A()’:
b.cpp:5:24: error: returning a value from a constructor
         return ((void)0);
```

What's the correct behavior here? And how can I adjust say a couple of macros like

```
#define MOO(a, b, retVal) \
    do                    \
        ...               \
        return (retVal);  \
   while(0)

#define FOO(a, b) MOO((a), (b), (void)0)
```

to work for c'tors as well? Is there a more c++-ish way to use decltype to return (void)0, -1, SOME_NONE and other default values for error handling aborts in such macros?

(A somewhat unrelated question is, approximately where in the code does gcc decide I'm returning a value from the c'tor?)

Comment: Silly idea to use a macro for such. Rethink your design, use a templated inline function instead!

Comment: While the idea is nice, it's not really an option for my case since it needs to be able to return from the current function.

Comment: Unless you're suggesting I manually manipulate the stack? Which isn't an option either, TBH

Comment: Would be interesting if returning via a void function call would work in a constructor, since from the answer below a constructor shouldn't use `return` with a value, while `void` explicitly states _no value_.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean, the spec says "Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined
behavior in a value-returning function." and I assume the same applies to a c'tor. But on the other hand `(void)0` is also a no-value, so I assumed it'd be equivalent.

Comment: _`(void)0` s also a no-value, so I assumed it'd be equivalent._ Where is that specified exactly?

Comment: clang is ok with `return f();` in the c'tor where `void f(){}` but gcc says a value is being returned, I assume it's equivalent to case 1. Yes I cannot find this in the spec, it feels like the expected behavior, that's why I'm asking this question in the first place, since I'm not too familiar with the spec.

Comment: Could be an over-simplification bug of the GCC parser, when inspecting `return` statements inside a constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the C++11 standard 12.1.8

> A return statement in the body of a constructor shall not specify a return value.

So it should be an error if you are returning a value from a constructor.

I believe the reason `return (void)0;` as a return in a constructor cannot be used is spelled out in 6.6.3.2

> A return statement with neither an expression nor a braced-init-list can be used only in functions that do not return a value, that is, a function with the return type cv void, a constructor (12.1), or a destructor (12.4).

Since `(void)0` is considered an expression it cannot be used in a constructor.

Comment: I'm not trying to return a value from the c'tor - I want to use an existing macro to do the equivalent of `return`. This macro calls an existing macro which does do a `return ...` with a `(void)0`.

Comment: @Guest86 but you are.  `return ...;` is going to return a value which is not allowed.  if you just want to exit from the constructor then you can use `return;`  like you would in a void function.

Comment: In a  normal function like `void moo() { return (void)0; }` is legal

Comment: @Guest86 Well constructors are not  normal functions and you shouldn't treat them like they are.

Comment: Yes that's a nice idea in principle but I'm looking for something more specific in the spec and cannot find it. I'd like to know if any of the cases I pointed out were expected to work and if there's a bug in gcc which I could take a look at. A vague feeling that it should go one way or the other doesn't help...

Comment: @Guest86 I made and edit to my answer.  let me know if the resolves it for you.

Comment: @NathanOliver, Because of the negative way it's written, it's a bit confusing but the way i see it, it means the reverse - That stuff like `return;` and `return (void)0;` cannot be used "regular" functions like `int f(){...}` and can only be used in void functions, c'tor and d'tor. But it doesn't say that `return (void)0;` cannot be used in c'tor, d'tor or `void foo() {..}`

Comment: @Guest86 Seems to give the same results using a template: http://ideone.com/fxY1Aa . Looks like no further argument is accepted with `return`, when called from a constructor.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, Yes I just tried it with some more versions, on gcc.godbolt.org and it looks like there's a new error for this starting from clang 3.5.0 (Last version it passes on is [clang 3.4.1](https://goo.gl/YsEyUr), saying `6 : error: constructor 'A' must not return void expression`. I guess they decided it's clear enough... Ok, thank you!

Comment: @Guest86 De Nada! I think we've both learned something new from this example ;-) ...